# How to display html content only on tablets and not on phone or desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element in html which contains a video tutorial which I want to display only when viewed on tablets and not on mobiles or desktops. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }` Note that these are the standard dimensions for iPad portrait orientation, the landscape orientation sits at `1024px`. There are many tablet devices with varying screen resolutions. You'll need various media queries to maintain a responsive design and layout throughout to accommodate these devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to solve this. The standard size for tablets is the range 768px to 992px. So, you can write two media queries: one for less than tablet-size(mobiles) and other for greater than tablet-size(desktops). And then set visibility to hidden and display to none. Any css you want to write for tablet size you can include it in your normal standard css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .divclass {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    /* your any other css styles */
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .divclass {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    /* your any other css styles */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using media queries of screen width:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:480px) { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:600px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:801px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Here with specific screen width you can set element's css `display:block;` and otherwise `display: none;`

So for your code it should be

```
@media (min-width:320px) { display: none; }
@media (min-width:801px) { display: block; }
@media (min-width:1025px) { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your div has a class named as 'container'.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
  .container{
   display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .container{
   display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px){
  .container{
   display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Use the following custom classes that I’ve put together! Note that with media queries (which these classes utilize), you’ll lose some browser support with older versions of Internet Explorer…So fix that with Respond.js!

In your stylesheet, add the following:

```
//medium+ screen sizes
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .desktop-only {
        display:block !important;
    }
}

//small screen sizes
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display:block !important;
    }

    .desktop-only {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

This gives you two classes — mobile-only and desktop-only.

As the names imply, if you assign something with the “mobile-only” class, then it will only display when the screen size is tiny (991px or below) [smartphones, some tablets], whereas “desktop-only” will show only on sizes 992px or higher.

These values are easily changed and the whole concept can be modified without issue. You could even add an “xl-desktop-only” class. To get you started…

```
//large resolutions only
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
...
}
```

Media queries are great for responsive design. Just make sure to not over do it and add way too many breakpoints. You’ll give yourself a headache if you try to account for everything.